# Auto formatting textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I am trying to add multiple texts from a datagridview to a textbox.My multiple texts i mean, the textbox will contain the value of cell(12) of all the rows of the dgvw.Here's my code :

```
Private Sub Button6_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    For Each row In Selected.dg2.Rows
        SendMail.totxt.Text &= row.Cells(12).Value
        SendMail.Show()
    Next
```

Now, cell 12 contains E-MAILS.My application is also an EMAIL app. What I want is, in the textbox, a comma(,)will be added automatically after every email address/every row's cell value. Any solution?

Comment: Research `String.Join". You dont need to show the form in the loop.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
For Each row In Selected.dg2.Rows
            SendMail.totxt.Text &= row.Cells(12).Value
            SendMail.totxt.Text &= ", "
        Next

totxt.Text = totxt.Text.Remove(totxt.TextLength - 2, 2)
```

You might also want to have a look at giving your email column a name, so that you can refer to it with `row.cells("email").value` instead of refering to it by index. This way, if you the number of columns in your datagrid ever change, your program wont break.